# ISO 8859-15 encoding detecting in Java?

Tags: java, encoding

How can I detect ISO 8859-15  encoding file in Java ? I found some Java Librairies Like :

jChardet
juniversalchardet
ApacheTika.

But I can't detecte some encoding like ISO 8859-15.

Comment: You would need complex linguistic analysis.  This is why MIME and HTTP have a Content-Type header;  it’s quite difficult to detect automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I remember solving something like this before using the Unicode table range lookup - if you typically know some of the characters that appear in the encoding set, you can lookup the character ranges on here:  https://unicode-table.com/en/20AC/

You can also check the decimal/hex values in tables such as:  http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html

With the likes of a decimal value you can just do a simple character check like so:

```
char c = '€'

// This seems to be the decimal range from the second link I provided
if(c >= 128 && c <= 159){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: my need is to detected file encoding not for character.

Comment: I would just open a stream on the file and read a couple of lines to detect?